# List items run outside of list and div area

Tags: html, css, overflow, html-lists, word-boundaries

I'm having an issue with a menu un-ordered list. Whereby the list items are over running the `<ul>` and `<div>` boundaries and only starting the next line once it has reach the edge of the screen.

Heres the website: http://finalonline.co.uk/mypics/gallery/categories/

Comment: The link has stopped working, the context is gone.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `float: left;` on the `li`s instead of `display: inline;`.

Just remember to also use `overflow: hidden;` on the parent element (the `ul`).

[Another option](http://jsfiddle.net/DdWJg/) would be to use: `display: inline-block`, but I'm not 100% sure about the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=inline-block).

Comment: Hi PeeHaa,that solution worked but I'd be interested to know why that way works when display:inline doesn't?

Comment: @Chrism lemme check your CSS and I will get back to you.

Comment: @Chrism very interesting question, to which I do not have an answer. I've created a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731189/why-do-inline-list-items-not-wrap) about this if you are interested.

Comment: @Chrism @PeeHaa - I think it's because there's no whitespace between the `li` tags.  Since there's no whitespace, the browser has nowhere to wrap the content until it's forced to wrap at the edge of the browser width.

Answer (score 27):

Do display: block; always... Never do `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;`

To fix the Unordered List from pouring out of the DIV, try going into the CSS and apply this:

```
ul {
list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make them `display: block`, not `inline`.

Comment: While that does make sure it doesn't go out of the container I don't think this is what the OP wants :P

Comment: My bad, totally thought OP didn't want them horizontal at all.  I need coffee.  :(

Answer (score 0):

To fix the Unordered List from pouring out of the DIV, I would suggest going into the CSS and adding a min-width.

so, for example if your parent  has a width:600px give the , within that div, a class and set a min-width:600px and this will keep the

items from stacking on top of one another and spilling outside the parent . worked for me.