# Why do inline list-items not wrap?

Tags: css

Please see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DdWJg/1/).

How come the `li`'s do not wrap to the next line?

I'm not looking for a solution, because there are several and they work. But I'm wondering WHY it doesn't wrap.

Cannot find anything in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes) about it (or I don't see it).

This question is related to an answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730803/list-items-run-outside-of-list-and-div-area/8730854#answer-8730854).

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no white space between them.

This sounds odd because the browser should be able to break between elements but you turned the elements into "words" using `display: inline;`. In this case, the browser "sees"

```
americaaustraliabannercabalcomputerfamilygeneralgwholsisraellastchaosmepeterpanphotospotbsPoTBSpsorforyzomtantratattoostemplatestravelweb_designwowmjboxquakeliveSpain_2011Sanatorio_de_Turberculososseverallsseveralls2bush_boake_allenodeon-colchestermoredartford
```

and it has no idea how to split this monster word.

Comment: +1 - think of it like having a very long sentencewithnospaces. There is no where to break for a wrap!

Comment: Aha of course because it is set to `inline` there has to be a `whitespace` between them. Good call.